# Subsequent transactions do not update the ledger in Hyperledger Fabric, yield iconsistent state

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on a small project to get myself familiar with the [Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/).

Currently, I have a small network, consisting of single peer, orderer and ca nodes (plus cli, chaincode and explorer), defined in [docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/tboloo/d25edd6d72913f90a7178c32912e489a)

I have installed sample chaincode, [chaincode_example02](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/chaincode_example02.go) to be more specific
The initial state of a ledger is A:100, B:200, defined by

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -C myc
```

When I execute the transfer everything works as expected

```
peer chaincode invoke -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}' -C myc
```

That is 10 units gets transfered from A to B

BUT
when I run let's say 3 transactions,

```
for i in {1..3}
do
    peer chaincode invoke -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}' -C myc
done
```

as a result I have three transactions in one block, but each of them identical, and as a result of those three transactions I have only 10 units transferred, whereas I would expect 30.

Do my question is: do I need to resort to the [high throughoutput](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/high-throughput) solution to have deterministic transactions? Or there is another way to achieve it (using events for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having this three transactions in the same block would mean that only one is successful, since all three of them writing into same key. The transaction to succeed is the first one, while two remaining will be considered as concurrent and hence invalidated.

The result of chaincode simulation/invocation is the Read-Write set, where it contains keys, values and modification version. Transactions trying to modify key with same or outdated version fails the MVCC (Multi Value Concurrency Control) check during block commit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Artem. Now, slightly rephrasing my question - how can I make sure that all subsequent transactions gets executed? I am looking into scenario wit few transaction, but occasional peeks with hundreds of transactions being executed almost immediately?

Comment: Ideally you need to listen to events to ensure first transaction got committed before sending a subsequent one which changes same key. An alternative would be to submit transaction at same rate ordering service cuts blocks, while not sure this is a really good solution. Another possibility would be to leverage UTXO model such that each transaction will update different key and to count total you will have to sum up over all keys in state. Note, this is a few possible solutions, while I'd imagine you can find more thru detailed design and architecture planing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I'll be exploring events then.